# samsung galaxy j1 apps don't work off sd card

Tags: app2sd, samsung-galaxy-j1

just bought a samsung galaxy j1. it has 8GB of memory but when i move my games/apps to the sd card, to free up more space on the phone, i cannot use them. it says this app is not installed. how do i fix this?